# Why does python convert my bytes-object into a int, when I put them in a new list?

Tags: python

**Intro**

Hi, I'm doing some fun cryptoanalysis exercises from [cryptopals](https://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/6), and I have now encountered an 'issue', that also has happened earlier, and I really don't understand.

currently, I have a ciphertext that I read from a file in the following way:

```
with open("6.txt", 'r') as infile:
        b64_encoded = infile.readlines()

ciphertext = b64decode('\n'.join([x.strip() for x in b64_encoded if x != ""]))
```

It's now a `bytes` objec, and looks like this when printed (this is just an excerpt):

```
b'\x1dB\x1fM\x0b\x0f\x02\x1fO\x13N<\x1aie\x1fI\x1c\x0eN\x13\x01\x0b\x07N\x1b\x01\x16E6\x00\x1e\x01Id T\x1d\x1dC3SNeR\x06\x00GT\x1c\rEM\x07\x04\x0cS\x12<\x0c\x1e\x08I\x1a\t\x11O\x14L!\x1aG+\x00\x05\x1dGY\x11\x04\t\x00d&\x07S\x007\x16\x06\x0c\x1a\x17A\x1d\x01RT0_\x00 \x13\n\x05GO\x12H\x08ENe>\x16\t8E\x06\x05\x08\x1aF\x07O\x1fYx~jb6\x0c\x1d\x0fA\rH\x06U\x1a\x1b\x00\x1dBt\x04\x1e\x01I\x1a\t\x11\x02Rz\x7fI\x00H:\x00\x1a\x13I\x1aOEH\x0f\x1d\rS\x04:\x01R\x19\x01\x0bA\x13\x06\x00L1_Sb\x15\x06\x07\t\x07T\x0b\x17A\x14\x16Iy35\x0b\x1b\x01\x05\x0fF\x07O\x1dNxNH\'R\x04\x07\x0cEXH\x08A\x00O T\x08t\x0b\x1d\x19I\x02\x00\x0e\x16\\\x00R0ie\x1fI\x02\x02T\x00\x01\x0b\x07N\x02\x10S\x01&\x10\x15M\x02\x07\x02\x1fO\x1bNx0i6R\n\x01\tT\x06\x07\tSN\x02\x10S\x08;\x10\x06\x05I\x0f\x0f\x10O;\x00:_G+\x1cId3OT\x02\ (...)
```

**context**

I have gotten to a point in the exercise, where I need to transpose this ciphertext, in accordance with a certain keylength that I know k, such that I can get a collection of strings where each string n, contains all the ciphertext characters that would have been encrypted with the n'th chararcter of the key.

That means that if I call my function `transpose(ciphertext, keyLen)` with arguments `transpose("123456789", 3)`, then my output would be:

```
[['1', '4', '7'], ['2', '5', '8'], ['3', '6', '9']]
```

**Problem**

Ok, the transpose function I have made looks like this:

```
def transpose(string, n):
    buckets = [[] for i in range(n)]
    i = 0
    for c in string:
        buckets[i].append( c)
        i += 1
        if i > (n-1):
            i = 0
    return buckets
```

When I use it on a string, it works just as expected, and outputs the expected output for "123456789".
But When I pass my 'bytes' ciphertext, then the output looks like this:

```
[[29, 54, 60, 55, 56, 116, 58, 53, 116, 38, 59, 116, 94, 58, 55, 49, 57, 57, 59, 61, 53, 34, 53, 58, 59, 116, 36, 32, 101, 48, 60, 51, 58, 116, 53, 58, 115, 116, 116, 49, 33, 13, 116, 60, 54, 59, 122, 59, 44, 53, 53, 116, 49, 50, 116, 45, 51, 49, 45, 59, 53, 38, 116, 94, 60, 48, 94, 59, 116, 49, 116, 54, 55, 116, 116, 58, 115, 33, 49, 59, 53, 58, 32, 49, 38, 53, 53, 45, 59, 116, 45, 61, 59, 94, 54, 32, 48, 55, 120, 39], [66, 0, 12, 22, 69, 4, 1, 11, 11, 16, 16, 12, 40, 66, 4, 69, 11, 0, 9, 11, 22, 0, 11, 66, 11, 10, 9, 69, 72, 69, 28, 12, 69, 111, 14, 69, 22, 13, 17, 23, 17, 10, 11, 69, 9, 11, 69, 8, 12, 69, 11, 44, 69, 23, 34, 12, 13, 23, 69, 69, 23, 10, 8, 54, 17, 69, 60, 18, 12, 4, 60, 10, 4, 4, 9, 69, 69, 23, 73, 8, 23, 28, 69, 69, 28, 28, 28, 69, 69, 111, 69, 0, 8, 53, 10, 13, 0, 73, 69, 12], [31, 30, 30, 6, 6, 30, 82, 27, 29, 21, 6, 6, 11, 94, 7, 120, 94, 82, 82, 85, 23, 82, 82, 82, 23, 20, 19, 7, 64, 120, 31, 30, 23, 59, 23, 95, 82, 19, 29, 94, 82, 7, 29, 31, 11, 83, 36, 27, 17, 5, 22, 17, 19, 23, 30, 28, 82, 23, 6, 26, 6, 7, 27, 2, 82, 31, 29, 28, 28, 0, 61, 22, 28, 28, 11, 17, 19, 23, 82, 23, 23, 6, 6, 22, 16, 82, 94, 21, 5, 62, 6, 92, 23, 30, 11, 19, 0, 82, 49, 17], [77, 1, 8, 12, 5, 1, 25, 1, 25, 77, 5, 77, 77, 77, 30, 44, 77, 103, 25, 77, 77, 0, 9, 29, 77, 11, 20, 29, 64, 43 (...)
```

And now my bytes have been converted to their integer representations?
This does'nt really make sense to me, since all I am doing is to iterate through the bytes and place them in buckets.
Why is it that these bytes are turned into integers if all you do is iterate over them?

Comment: ``bytes`` *are* sequences of 1 byte *integers*, not of "individual bytes".

Comment: [PEP 358](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0358/) and [PEP 3137](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3137/) both say *that* ``bytes`` are sequences of integers, but do not give a rationale for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I remember this problem in cryptopals, I was facepalming when I understood how this trick works.

As MisterMiyagi said it, `bytes` is not a sequence of "bytes", but a sequence of `int`s.

If you index into an `str`, you get another `str`:

```py
>>> type("abc"[0])
<class 'str'>
```

But with bytes:

```
>>> type(b"abc"[0])
<class 'int'>
```

So it's your `for` loop that 'converts' them to `int`. This can be directly done by `list`:

```
>>> list(b"abc")
[97, 98, 99]
```

But the reverse is also easily possible:

```
>>> bytes([97, 98, 99])
b'abc'
```